# R: Sorting Values in Pivot Table (rpivottable)

Tags: r, pivot-table, rpivottable

I am new using `PivotTable` in R and I am looking to sort (from largest to smallest) the value within the table (the "vals" in R). I am working with passengers data and I want the largest amount of passengers appearing in the firsts rows of the table. It now sorted alphabetically by the name of the Airport (my rows) but I am more interested in sorting it by the number of passengers (my values within the table).
Thanks

I have a basic line of code:

```
rpivotTable(data1, rows="Airport", col="Direct", aggregatorName="Sum", 
                                                vals="Passengers", rendererName="Heatmap")
```

Here is the data:

> Airport Direct Passengers  
>   CAN  Direct 100  
>   CDG Indirect 5000 
>   CMG Indirect 200  
>   DNM Direct 10000  
>   LAX Indirect 200  
>   MEL Direct 20  
>   YUL Indirect 4000

Comment: please make code reproducible by sharing example data.

Comment: Sure, here is example data:

Comment: Where? Please include it in the post.

Comment: Sorry I just included it.. Though I guess the format is not good for the Forum. Couldn't find a way of doing it properly.

Comment: Are you looking for `df[order(df$Passengers, decreasing =  T),]` ?

Comment: I gues but I don't know that `df ` function. I just tried to include that line of code and I have an error message. How do I include that in the code then?
>Error in df$Passengers : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: `df` is the name of the `data.frame`, so in your case `data1`.

Comment: Thank you @moto. But how do you include that to make it work within the `rpivottable`. function? I tried to do it as the `sorter ` parameter but still, the results displayed the order by the name of the airport and not by the number of passengers.. 
`rpivotTable(data1, rows="Airport.Pair", col="Direct", aggregatorName="Sum", 
            vals=("Passengers"), rendererName="Heatmap", sorter = data1[order(data1$Passengers, decreasing = TRUE),])`

Answer (score 0):

The function you want to study is `order`.  To share your example data in the future, you can use `dput(data1)` and copy and paste the contents into the question.

```
data1 <- structure(list(Airport = structure(1:7, .Label = c("CAN", "CDG", 
"CMG", "DNM", "LAX", "MEL", "YUL"), class = "factor"), Direct = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Direct", "Indirect"), class = "factor"), 
    Passengers = c(100L, 5000L, 200L, 10000L, 200L, 20L, 4000L
    )), .Names = c("Airport", "Direct", "Passengers"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Using order, we can arrange your data as you want it by

```
data1[order(data1$Passengers, decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

You can do more multiple arrangements, such as ordered by `Direct` and then by `Passengers` using

```
data1[order(data1$Direct, data1$Passengers), ]
```

But the previous line requires that all of the ordering be either ascending or all descending.  If you want a mix, I recommend using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
arrange(data1, Direct, desc(Passengers))
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. However, how do you include it into the `rpivottable` line of code ? I need the data within the `Pivot Table` to be in descending order. I made it descending in the data frame but when I am doing the Pivot Table, it is not kept. It uses the data in the row to sort the value. There is the `sorter` function for the row but not for the data..

Comment: I just spent 30 minutes exploring `rpivotTable` trying to figure it out, and as far as I can tell, it requires some javascript, which isn't something I'm very good at.  And I'm even worse with pivot tables.  Left to my own devices, I'd  avoid using it.

Comment: Oh so it is more difficult than I have thought. Thanks for trying @Benjamin.